# Using implicit function theorem to examine the relation between variables

Tags: equation-solving

I have an implicit function with seven variables defined as follows:

$F(g,a,b,c,d,e,f)=2g^5 (1+g)^{-(2+a+b)} \Big(f(c-1)(e-1)(1+g)^a - (d-1)(1+g)^b \big(1+ef+(c-1)(1+f)(1+g)^a\big)\Big)=0$

All variables are subject to certain restrictions:

$-1<g<1$,

$0<b<a$ and

$0<c,d,e,f<1$.

Now I would like to examine how changes in each of $a,b,c,d,e,f$ affect $g$. Maybe I should use an implicit function theorem:

$\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial g}}$

and see if this expression is positive or negative. It is most probable that it will not be a clear-cut positive/negative but will be positive/negative 'under certain conditions'.

Anyway, for this, I have first coded the implicit function:

```
F[g_,a_,b_,c_,d_,e_,f_] := 2g^5 * (1 + g)^(- 2 - b - a) * (f * (c - 1) * (e - 1) * (1 + g)^a - (d - 1) * (1 + g)^b * (1 + e * f + (c - 1) * (f + 1) * (1 + g)^a )))
```

And the partial derivatives are coded as:

```
D[F[g,a,b,c,d,e,f],a]
D[F[g,a,b,c,d,e,f],g]
```

These produce very scary results which do not allow to see if positive or negative. Is there any way to check these with Mathematica? Or, is this the right way to proceed at all?

Comment: The code for the implicit function does not correspond to the initial equation. Please correct one or the other.

Comment: Thank you Bob, I have corrected it. They are now the same.

Comment: When `g` is negative it looks like you get complex values due to the powers.